# Designing ASIC Chip for Enterprise

Tags: asic

I am new here and hope to glean some expert opinions.
I am a disabled veteran and will be starting a bitcoin mining enterprise
in the near future. I have done some research and feel that inquiring
with some large asic makers to make a more profitable system is the smarter way to go. Can someone please provide some insight on the following build to mine bitcoin.

1. Power Circuitry: Texas Instruments TL7700 Voltage Supervisor
2. Communications: SHA 512 or Whirlpool 512
3. 5 nm die
4. BGA Design: Texas Instruments CFCBGA GDZ or best applicable model
5. Processor: Multicore DSP+ARM KeyStone II System-on-Chip (SoC) 66AK2H14
6. Cooling: EVGA Kingpin
7. PSU: Cisco XPS 2200 x 14
8. Server: ASIC Chips x 30

I am budgeted at $150 - $200k for the entire server setup including ASIC's.
A separate budget of $100k will fund a 10 Kw solar array.

As I'm shooting for the stars, my goals are 150 TH/s per chip and 1000 watts per chip.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Will you design the ASIC yourself, or have you budgeted something to hire somebody to do it? Good ASIC designers probably start at $200k/year.

Comment: Don't do it. You would be throwing your money away.

Comment: Entire companies often cannot afford an ASIC.

Comment: Your estimates are too low by about 10x.

Comment: 10x really? All the components are existing, someone would just be putting it all together.

Comment: If you are "designing an ASIC", _by definition_ the component doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 5):

A budget of $150-200k is unlikely to even cover the NRE costs for fabricating a part at 5nm, let alone the cost of designing one. Your project is futile.

The rest of your "build" is mostly nonsense. XPS 2200 is an accessory for Cisco routers; CFCBGA is a proprietary package used by TI; EVGA Kingpin is a model of gaming graphics card… none of this makes any sense.